# Book an appointment in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to book a specific time for the user (start hour and end hour ) and no one else can book at the same time
Example Like :
John made an appointment on the 5th day of the month at 7 to 8 o'clock
i want no one else can book at the same time

How I can Do This in Models Django

I could not find a solution to this problem

Comment: Before booking an appointment, search the existing appointments for that day and make sure the requested appointment doesn't overlap with any of them.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: Can you share the *current* state of the models?

Comment: @JohnGordon and get a possible race condition. You'll either have to lock the whole table (can't be done with pure Django ORM, can have sever performance impact) or enforce this on a DB level (like `EXCLUDE USING GIST (time_slot WITH &&)` in postgres, smth similar may exist in other databases, requires tweaking table creation SQL in the first migration once).